# C style array in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays

With all the useful things you get from NSArray and NSMutableArray, why would you ever use a "C Style" array with Objective-C objects?

```
NSString *array[] = {@"dog", @"cat", @"boy"};
```

Comment: Further OT, is there a meta discussion of exactly this c-tag problem? I'm myself pretty grumpy about c++ and obj-c questions using the c tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For short, fixed arrays, the availability of a nice compact initialization syntax (as you've demonstrated) can be nice. In certain cases, a C style array may also offer a performance benefit compared to using NSArray. Another thing that comes to mind is that NSArray doesn't offer any built in support for multidimensional arrays, while multidimensional C arrays are easy.

And of course, there's the fact that you can only store objects in NSArray, not C-primitive types, but you asked specifically about using C arrays with Objective-C objects.

Comment: +1. The performance benefit can be huge, since the compiler can apply a lot of optimization, which can't be done when using `NSArray`, because of typical objective-c features such as categories and method swizzling, which (in theory) could alter `NSArray`'s behavior.

Comment: Can you still use the usual C idiom `sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])` to get the count? Could you use `sizeof(array) / sizeof([array class])` ?

Answer (score 1):

All useful things come at a price.

Ever try making an `NSArray` of `ints`? You can't. You **MUST** use `NSNumber`.

Why? Because `NSArray` doesn't know what to do with things it doesn't know how to memory-manage... and the only things that conform to it's memory-management requirements are things based on `NSObject`.

It's just one example, but there are plenty of others.

Bottom line is, there is rarely ever one single "best" answer to anything. `NSArray` is no exception.